# Delete behind the second modal box in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I have a modal that use Bootstrap to which when I press a button habre a small second modal which when opened the second modal modal blocking the first but the second modal behind a table covering almost the entire second modal appears as delete the picture ?

Code:

```
<div aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;" id="stack2" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1"><div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Stack Two</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <h4>Some Input</h4>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <input class="col-md-12 form-control" type="text">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <input class="col-md-12 form-control" type="text">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <input class="col-md-12 form-control" type="text">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <input class="col-md-12 form-control" type="text">
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn yellow">Ok</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

**jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/fs8qL3oq/

Comment: .modal-dialog{z-index:1400}

Comment: not be solved with that